# Page with redirect - https://www.example.com/post-url/www.example.com Error

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, url-parsing

I am using WordPress Rishi Theme

my website making this url in google search console. and Screaming Frog SEO Spider software also detect this url

all pages and all post same error but this page is not exist

https://www.example.com/post-url/www.example.com

I am also share this problem with cPanel service provider they are telling this is website mistake not a cPanel

somebody help

what is this ?

How to fix this url ?

https://www.example.com/post-url/www.example.com

to

https://www.example.com/post-url